# refresh desktop using batch

Tags: batch-file, refresh, desktop

I need to refresh the desktop ussing batch is this possible?

I have found the following VBscript that refreshes the containing window however, the desktop needs to be refreahed and its not the containing window

anyways around this?

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
```

thx-

Answer (score 7):

You may try this:

```
rundll32 user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Or this:

```
ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
```

It is, however, version dependent.

Comment: Okay version dependant? We have several versions like vista, 98, xp and ME though all are home pc (none run 64-bit).

Comment: On Xp it works (at least in mine) ... the rest I've no way to test. Try it :). And read my comment under your question, please.

Answer (score 4):

On Win7 this can be done by calling the function "[SHChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762118.aspx)" from "shell32.dll".
The problem is that AFAIK this function can't be successfully loaded using "rundll32.exe", so instead use a program that can do it.

---

## Compiled EXE

Use [this CLI Refresh Tool from sepago website](https://www.sepago.com/blog/2014/01/22/freeware-desktoprefresh-tool) (32/64 bit images available for download)

## AHK (AutoHotKey)

```
DllCall("Shell32\SHChangeNotify", UInt, 0x08000000, UInt, 0, UIntP, 0, UIntP, 0)
```

## AutoIt

```
DllCall("shell32.dll", "none", "SHChangeNotify", "long", 0x8000000, "uint", BitOR(0x0, 0x1000), "ptr", 0, "ptr", 0)
```

Comment: Did anyone try this with Windows 8.1? The CLI Refresh tool does not seem to do anything.

Comment: The link to the refresh tool on the sepago site is dead.

Comment: Dead: that includes WayBackMachine: the page is not there either. Nor in archive.is.

Comment: It seems like a similar tool. Maybe it will work. https://helgeklein.com/blog/2007/11/free-tool-refresh-the-desktop-programmatically/

Comment: P.S. anyone can easily compile AHK script into exe.

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
ie4uinit.exe -show
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be strictly native commands?

If you can use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/), you can use the following script:

```
WinActivate("Program Manager") 
Send("{F5}")
```

### EDIT

This works on XP. I have not tried it on Vista or 7.

Comment: Gah! And here we have the reason why Windows is forced to name the desktop window "Program Manager", even 15 years after Windows 3 died.

Comment: @Joey That's a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     @echo off
     taskkill /fi "imagename eq explorer.exe" /f
     CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
     DEL IconCache.db /a
     START explorer.exe
```

Comment: `“imagename eq explorer.exe”` corrected to `"imagename eq explorer.exe"` (note the `"`)